# Modal popup open while calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, jquery-events

I am using the below code to show the login modal popup. Its working well. But i need another one function to show the model popup without button click. If i call that function means the same popup should be appear. Please help me to do this.

```
<a id="modal_trigger" tabindex="-1" href="#modal" class="btn">Login </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({ top: 200, overlay: 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

        $(function () {
            // Calling Login Form
            //$("#login_form").click(function () {
            //$(".user_login").show();
            //return false;
            //});

        })
</script>

<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display: none;">
        <header class="popupHeader">
            <span class="header_title"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp; Login</i></span>
            <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </header>
        <section class="popupBody">
            <!-- Social Login -->
            <div class="user_login">
                <form>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" />
                    <br />

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input id="remember" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="remember">Remember me on this computer</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="action_btns">
                        <div class="one_half"><a href="#" class="btn back_btn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i> Back</a></div>
                        <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="login_form" class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <a href="#" class="forgot_password">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
            </section>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#modal_trigger').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

try this it will show the popup

`$('#login_form').trigger('click');`

Comment: But i use the below code $('#modal_trigger').trigger('click');